# Recovering mandrill data to txt using php

Tags: php, mandrill

I'm trying to transfer the POST data mandrill sends to my URL. I'm sending it to a .php file.
This is the entire code of the file I'm sending the POST:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
    $f = fopen("webhook_data.txt","a");
    $data = $_POST["mandrill_events"];
    fwrite($f, $data);
    fclose($f);
?>
```

The POST is reaching my url for sure. It must be a way, a trigger wich when i send the POST somehow the php file executes and create the txt.

On the other hand, if I try to manually execute the php file ( ./file.php ) it returns me the error: Undefined index: mandrill_events.

Anyone knows how I can do that?

Edit:

It's not a trigger problem, apache deals with it correctly. Somehow, mandrill doesn't send me anything. Any ideas?

Comment: on cli there is no post / get / request ... you need to handle the request, to do this action on the file the request is sent to!

Answer (score 0):

The code was ok, I don't know why but mandrill has started to send the data this morning XD.

Answer (score 0):

$data = $_POST["mandrill_events"];

$data variable hold the $_POST data. If the php file need to be posted other ways show the error Undefined index: mandrill_events, because the mandrill_events variable is empty. For solve this error you can use

$data = @$_POST["mandrill_events"];

The problem may be mandrill_events is empty. Please check it first, and you have need to post the php file. You can try using $data = $_REQUEST["mandrill_events"]; I think it's solve your problem. Thanks